# Adding lists to firebase with VUEJS 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, pinia

I have a list of items 'order' which I want to add to my cloud firestore.

```
order: [
        {
     
          product: 'Tea',
          productivity: '15',
          quantity: '10',
        },
        {
          
          product: 'fruits',
          productivity: '15',
          quantity: '11',
        },
      ],
```

before my app was simple where I could add only one product and this function was working fine (this formula comes from pinia store)

```
    async addOrder(clientsid, newOrderProduct, newOrderProductivity, newOrderQuantity) {
      const storeAuth = useStoreAuth()

      await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', storeAuth.user.id, 'clients', clientsid, 'orders'), {
        
        product: newOrderProduct,
        productivity: newOrderProductivity,
        quantity: newOrderQuantity,
        productionTime: newOrderQuantity / newOrderProductivity
   
            
      })
  
    },
```

but now I want to add multiple products at the same time. Currently I am adding data locally. Basically it is simple cart but I couldn't find something which would suit my case.

This is code where I call function addOrder in my component.

```
  const addOrders = () => {

    storeOrders.addOrder(newOrderName.value, newOrderProduct.value, newOrderProductivity.value, newOrderQuantity.value)
    
    newOrderProduct.value
    newOrderProductivity.value = ''
    newOrderQuantity.value = ''



  }
```

Comment: You want each item in orders array to be a document in orders sub-collection ?

Comment: yes, but every item would have his own unique id.

Comment: Can you please show how are you calling `addOrder` now? You could call the function for each item in the array or alternatively use [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)

Comment: I just added in my question code of how I am calling addOrder in my component. but again this works when there is one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for you, you can adapt it to your code, when adding several products at the same time you have to create a map and convert it asynchronously, in this way the article would have its own unique identification

```
const order =  [
  {

    product: 'Tea',
    productivity: '15',
    quantity: '10',
  },
  {
    
    product: 'fruits',
    productivity: '15',
    quantity: '11',
  },
];

order.map(async(item)=> {
  await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', storeAuth.user.id, 'clients', clientsid, 'orders'), {
    product: item.product,
    productivity: item.productivity,
    quantity: item.quantity,
    productionTime: item.quantity / item.productivity
  })
})
```